# Passing an array out of a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a list of all of the files inside of a tree structure.  I found the following code that I found online that does this but outputs the folder and file names to an error log. (I am using BetterLog to send this to a spreadsheet.  I would like to have the information saved to an array as the function run, problem is that the function is recursive and I can not figure out how to resolve this problem.

```
function getChildFolders(parent) {
Logger =    BetterLog.useSpreadsheet('1nJ3fTFYQgwwXYik3LqAoX2M1KHj4lskrxyX0Y9p6ci8');

var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

var childFolder = childFolders.next();

Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
Logger.log("Folder URL:  " + childFolder.getUrl());

var files = childFolder.getFiles();

while (files.hasNext()) {

// Print list of files inside the folder
  Logger.log(files.next().getName());  
  }

  // Recursive call for any sub-folders
  getChildFolders(childFolder);
```

}

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just pass on the array as a parameter for the function, like this:

```
function getChildFolders(parent,array) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

    var childFolder = childFolders.next();

    array.push("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    array.push("Folder URL:  " + childFolder.getUrl());

    var files = childFolder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {

      // Print list of files inside the folder
      array.push(files.next().getName());  
    }

    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
    getChildFolders(childFolder, array);
  }

  return array;
}

function test() {
  var array = getChildFolders(DriveApp.getRootFolder(), []);
  Logger.log(array);
}
```

Comment: Does it make and hold a copy of the entire array each time the function is called recursively?

Comment: No, you have to create the array and pass it to the function, which then passes it to itself on the recursive calls. There's only one single array throughout the whole execution. There's no copy or recreating arrays.

Comment: Thanks you. That answers my question perfectly.